# how to change winkey + (left/right) keyboard-shortcut behavior

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

When you use the shortcut: winkey+left / winkey + right, the current window is attached to the side of your screen by 50% width.
i would like to change this behavior, and attach it by 33.3% width

visual explanation:

[image: desired window shortcut behavior]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The snap size is fixed for Windows 7 and Windows 8.

If you are looking for a custom size you might have to look for a third party program.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you can't edit the size, but you could have a play with something from  [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb964665.aspx)

I personally have not used this program since I haven't had the need, but it might do what you want and it's from a 'trusted' source...

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, i found a good solution.
This is an open source called [GridMove](http://jgpaiva.dcmembers.com/gridmove.html)

the shortcut i'm using is <kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>numpad number</kbd> instead of <kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>left/right arrow</kbd>

if it helps, this is my 3-monitor `.grid` file (should be located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\GridMove\Grids\jossef.grid`

<kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> => left bottom

<kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> => center bottom

<kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> => right bottom

<kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> => left full

<kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> => center full

<kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> => right full

<kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> => left top

<kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> => center top

<kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> => right top

**jossef.grid:**

```
[Groups]
 NumberOfGroups = 9

[1]
 TriggerTop    = [MonitorReal1Top] +20
 TriggerBottom = [MonitorReal1Bottom] -20
 TriggerLeft   = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /9
 TriggerRight  = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3
 GridTop     = [Monitor1Bottom] / 2
 GridBottom  = [Monitor1Bottom]
 GridLeft    = [Monitor1Left]
 GridRight   = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3

[2]
 TriggerTop    = [MonitorReal1Top] +20
 TriggerBottom = [MonitorReal1Bottom] -20
 TriggerLeft   = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /12 *5
 TriggerRight  = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /12 *7
 GridTop     = [Monitor1Bottom] / 2
 GridBottom  = [Monitor1Bottom] 
 GridLeft    = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3
 GridRight   = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3 *2

[3]
 TriggerTop    = [MonitorReal1Top] +20 
 TriggerBottom = [MonitorReal1Bottom] -20
 TriggerLeft   = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3 *2
 TriggerRight  = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /9 *8
 GridTop     = [Monitor1Bottom] / 2
 GridBottom  = [Monitor1Bottom]
 GridLeft    = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3 *2
 GridRight   = [Monitor1Right]

[4]
 TriggerTop    = [MonitorReal1Top] +20
 TriggerBottom = [MonitorReal1Bottom] -20
 TriggerLeft   = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /9
 TriggerRight  = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3
 GridTop     = [Monitor1Top]
 GridBottom  = [Monitor1Bottom]
 GridLeft    = [Monitor1Left]
 GridRight   = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3

[5]
 TriggerTop    = [MonitorReal1Top] +20
 TriggerBottom = [MonitorReal1Bottom] -20
 TriggerLeft   = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /12 *5
 TriggerRight  = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /12 *7
 GridTop     = [Monitor1Top]
 GridBottom  = [Monitor1Bottom]
 GridLeft    = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3
 GridRight   = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3 *2

[6]
 TriggerTop    = [MonitorReal1Top] +20
 TriggerBottom = [MonitorReal1Bottom] -20
 TriggerLeft   = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3 *2
 TriggerRight  = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /9 *8
 GridTop     = [Monitor1Top]
 GridBottom  = [Monitor1Bottom]
 GridLeft    = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3 *2
 GridRight   = [Monitor1Right]

[7]
 TriggerTop    = [MonitorReal1Top] +20
 TriggerBottom = [MonitorReal1Bottom] -20
 TriggerLeft   = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /9
 TriggerRight  = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3
 GridTop     = [Monitor1Top]
 GridBottom  = [Monitor1Bottom] / 2
 GridLeft    = [Monitor1Left]
 GridRight   = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3

[8]
 TriggerTop    = [MonitorReal1Top] +20
 TriggerBottom = [MonitorReal1Bottom] -20
 TriggerLeft   = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /12 *5
 TriggerRight  = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /12 *7
 GridTop     = [Monitor1Top] 
 GridBottom  = [Monitor1Bottom] / 2
 GridLeft    = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3
 GridRight   = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3 *2

[9]
 TriggerTop    = [MonitorReal1Top] +20
 TriggerBottom = [MonitorReal1Bottom] -20
 TriggerLeft   = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3 *2
 TriggerRight  = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /9 *8
 GridTop     = [Monitor1Top]  
 GridBottom  = [Monitor1Bottom] / 2
 GridLeft    = [MonitorReal1Left] + [MonitorReal1Width] /3 *2
 GridRight   = [Monitor1Right]
```

---

To apply,

1. right click the tray icon - [image]
2. Templates
3. `-Refresh this list-`
4. `jossef.grid`

[image]